# Static variables in Events Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

Why cant i use static variables in events handling methods like this

```
private void redoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        static int a=0;
        rtbScript.Redo();
 }
```

I am getting an error The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item
Can i know any solution to this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local static variables in Timer.Tick event (Stopping a Timer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105780/local-static-variables-in-timer-tick-event-stopping-a-timer)

Comment: you cant use static members in a method!Instead "make the event static"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variables are class members and belong to the class (their scope is the class)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can have static variables *inside* a function in C#. I guess that's a C++ feature only.

Answer (score 1):

Statics are defined at the class level, not at the method level.  Move the variable outside our your method definition and make it a static class level variable.

```
public class MyClass {
  static int a = 0;
  private void redoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        rtbScript.Redo();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only members of a class can be static. Why would yuo want static to begin with?